# swt imports in Eclipse RCP failing

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I seem to be going round in circles here.

I had a series of related projects that were working, and something has caused it not to work.  The symptoms are that any source file using an import from an org.eclipse.swt bundle will not compile, with the red line being under the import statement(s).

Some of the projects have a plugin dependency on org.eclipse.swt jar, but others don't.  If I try to add such a dependency, org.eclipse.swt isn't offered as a bundle, but only the platform dependent bundles such as org.eclipse.win32.win32.x86 can be added from the dependencies tab in the Manifest editor.
The build path accessed through right clicking on the source file in the Package Explorer shows the dependency too.

If I explicitly add the org.eclipse.win32.win32.x86 jar to the build path, most of the projects will build, but a couple still have errors ( the offending line in these is 
        SWTApplicationComposite window = new SWTApplicationComposite(parent);
and the obcection is to parent - as an unrecognised class Composite although it has been declared without a problem!)

I have tried deleting the dependency and then adding it as a new dependency, but the compiler still fails to find it.

Any clues as to what I might have missed (I'm doing this as part of an RCP development)

Answer (score 1):

I think the target platform that is set is not able to recognize platform specific jars( win 64 bit or 32 bit).

1. Create target configuration file and select win32 as configruation in the editor
2. you see "set as target platform" link on top right corner of the target config file editor.
3. click that link. it sets your target platform to win32 specific( recognizes all swt win32 bundles)